# Inspecting verbose ActiveRecord objects in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, inspect

I'm inspecting an ActiveRecord object in pry and the Rails console, but one of the attributes is really verbose.

```
my_record.document.to_s.length # => 45480
```

How can I view the record, telling Rails that I only want a few dozen characters from `my_record.document` before truncating it with an ellipsis?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `truncate` method from action view to do this. For instance, if you wanted to truncate to 300 characters, including the ellipsis, then you could do the following.

```
truncate(my_record.document.to_s, length: 300)
```

You'll first have to include ActionView::Helper methods in order to have `truncate` available in your console.

```
include ActionView::Helpers
```

This is also trivial to do in pure Ruby if you want to go that route:

```
max_length = 10
"This could be a really long string".first(max_length - 3).ljust(max_length, "...")
```

outputs:

```
"This co..."
```

**EDIT**

If you want to truncate inspection for a single attribute override the `attribute_for_inspect`:

For instance, you could truncate display of the `document` column to 300 characters (including ellipsis) as follows:

**In your model:**

```
def attribute_for_inspect(attr_name)
  if attr_name.to_sym == :document
    max_length = 300
    value = read_attribute(attr_name).to_s

    # You should guard against nil here.
    value.first(max_length - 3).ljust(max_length, "...")
  else
    super
  end
end
```

`attr_for_inspect` is defined in `ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods` if you want to see how it works: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb#L296.